# iPhone UIDatePicker in Landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

iPhone UI Componenet UIDatePicker does not support Landscape mode?
it scratches 2/3 of the width in Landscape mode only.

How to make it use up full width (480px)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to manually re/set the UIDatePickers' subviews bounds like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for (UIView * subview in datePicker.subviews) {
        subview.frame = datePicker.bounds;
    }
}
```

Everything is nicely described in this article:
[Using UIDatePicker in landscape mode](http://web.archive.org/web/20111228010043/http://www.llamagraphics.com/developer/using-uidatepicker-landscape-mode)

Comment: The link is now dead. Is there any chance of someone recovering the information it contained and posting it here? Thanks.