# how to customize date-picker in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, landscape, uidatepicker

I am having date picker in landscape mode .i adjusted it coordinate to fit in landscape mode.

But it is looking like **imageA** but i want it to look like **imageB**.
how can i do that.

**ImageA.**

[image]

**imageB.**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is helpful -

[iPhone Landscape-Only Utility-Template Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525737/iphone-landscape-only-utility-template-application)

http://www.llamagraphics.com/developer/UIDatePicker.html

[iPhone UIDatePicker in Landscape mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331752/iphone-uidatepicker-in-landscape-mode)